Expo App crashes when I press a button that runs a navigation.navigate() method
Until 2 days ago I think my app works fine, now, I saw some errors when I run my react native project on IOS. I use Expo: "expo": "^51.0.2" as version.
I got these errors:
 ERROR  Warning: Main: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
    in Main (created by PhoneInput)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PhoneInput)
    in PhoneInput (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in SignUpScreenBusiness (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by Navigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Navigation)
    in Navigation (created by App)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  Warning: CountryPicker: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
    in CountryPicker (created by Main)
    in ThemeProvider (created by Main)
    in Main (created by PhoneInput)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PhoneInput)
    in PhoneInput (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in SignUpScreenBusiness (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by Navigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Navigation)
    in Navigation (created by App)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  Warning: FlagButton: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
    in FlagButton (created by CountryPicker)
    in CountryPicker (created by Main)
    in ThemeProvider (created by Main)
    in Main (created by PhoneInput)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PhoneInput)
    in PhoneInput (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in SignUpScreenBusiness (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by Navigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Navigation)
    in Navigation (created by App)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  Warning: Flag: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
    in Flag
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by FlagButton)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by FlagButton)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (created by FlagButton)
    in FlagButton (created by CountryPicker)
    in CountryPicker (created by Main)
    in ThemeProvider (created by Main)
    in Main (created by PhoneInput)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PhoneInput)
    in PhoneInput (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in SignUpScreenBusiness (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by Navigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Navigation)
    in Navigation (created by App)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  Warning: CountryModal: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
    in CountryModal (created by CountryPicker)
    in CountryPicker (created by Main)
    in ThemeProvider (created by Main)
    in Main (created by PhoneInput)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PhoneInput)
    in PhoneInput (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by SignUpScreenBusiness)
    in SignUpScreenBusiness (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by Navigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by Navigation)
    in Navigation (created by App)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)

From what I've read on this version of expo defaultProps are not supported anymore, but these references are from installed packages.. how can I solve this issue? Can this influence the way that app is running?
